# Android Nougat (7.0 / API 24) rating count is wrong in OnRatingBarChangeListener

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am using `RatingBar` in Android Nougat (7.0) And using `OnRatingBarChangeListener` to detect the rating changes.

It is giving wrong value of rating in callback method. So suppose if i click on 2nd star it gives me 3.0 and if i click 4th star it gives me count as 5.0 .

Another thing which i have noticed is count depends on where exactly i am clicking. If i click on first half part of star it returns proper count and if i click on second half of star it adds +1 to count.

[Video link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_er4uRW9U5hM2puT3V1Q2hpY2c)

ACTIVITY :

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2);

    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
      @Override public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Rating is %f : fromUser %b", rating, fromUser));

        mTextView.setText(String.format("Rating is %f ", rating));
      }
    });
```

XML :

```
  <RatingBar
      android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:isIndicator="false"
      android:stepSize="1"
      android:rating="5"
      />
```

Comment: I'me experiencing this same issue; but it's only in API 24. This is fixed in API 25.

Any fixes for using a ratingbar in API level 24?

Comment: i don't have any solution yet on this for API 24. What i did is changed rating bar layout with star Images if API level is 24 and on click of same somehow managed the view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can effectively backport the fix by doing:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { 
  try { 
    Field field = 
AbsSeekBar.class.getDeclaredField("mTouchProgressOffset"); 
    field.setAccessible(true); 
    field.set(mRatingBar, 0.6f); 
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
}
```

See the [original commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/1d33c3f3a379440f8f797c296490b07107bfe9e5) that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in API 24:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37114040

Seems the only fix is to upgrade (if your manufacturer/carrier ever releases an upgrade to you) or use some sort of custom rating bar implementation for API 24.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very simple workaround for this problem, on your rating bar, use step as `"0.1"` and on Your `OnRatingBarChangeListener` use this code snippet;

```
int rating = (int)Math.Ceiling(args.Rating);
if (rating != args.Rating)
{
    ratingBar.Rating = rating;
    return;
} 

// now the rating will be the tapped star
// you can do what you must do here
```

p.s. i wrote this in Xamarin.Android but I am pretty sure you can easily make it apply to java by changing the ceil function and using the setter for the rating of the RatingBar